# Powershell delete files older than 30 days but exclude certain folders and their contents

Tags: windows, powershell

Here is my current code but sadly it deletes excluded folder contents. I want to keep folder contents that are inside an excluded folder.

I've been trying for days but can't find a solution. Maybe this is a PowerShell limitation?

```
$path = "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\testfolder"
$exclude = @('FOLDERNAME', 'filename.txt')
$lastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite} | Remove-Item
```

Method 2 (doesn't function) :

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite}
$path = "C:\Users\louisp\Desktop\testfolder"
$exclude = @('oldkeep', 'oldkeep2', 'important')
$lastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

foreach ($item in $results) {
   $noExeption = $true
   foreach($exeption in $exclude){
      if($item.name -eq $exeption){
         $noExeption = $false
         break
      }
   }
   if($noExeption) {
      remove-item $item
   }
}
```

Comment: this is not something very easy to do because first you need to exclude all parent folders where they have a child named `filename.txt` I dont think powershell has something builtin to do something like. you would need to query each folder recursively yourself

Comment: I didn't mean this can't be done with powershell tho

Comment: Exclude does not use an array.  You need to use Any along with -Not : Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name; ($_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite) -And -Not ([Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$exclude,[Func[object,bool]] {param($x) $name.Contains($x) }))} | Remove-Item

Answer (score 1):

There is the code I use. maybe a little rustic, but it works.

```
$age = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -Exclude Z*, FolderName | foreach{
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -le $age){
        Remove-Item $_.fullname -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to following workaround art two:

```
$results= Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite} 
foreach ($item in $results){
   $notExeption=$true
   foreach($exeption in $exclude){
      if($item.name -eq $exeption){
         $noExeption=$false
         break
      }
   }
   if($noexeption){
      remove-item -LiteralPath $item.name
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution but it doesnt seem to function. It doesn't delete folders and files older than 30 days while protecting folders and their contents for those added to exclusions.

I have added the attempted code in the main question as part 2.

Comment: Edited answer: remove-item -LiteralPath $item.name